# Jacob 1.14.3 DLL no detected by the java.libary.path using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dll, jacob

I am trying to implement the library JACOB to communicate to some payments devices such as PINPADs. I have created a java project but when the main class execute the method that use the DLL in the runtime gives a error `no jacob-1.14.3-x64 in java.library.path`

**Here you can find what I am using to build the project:**

- Operating System: Windows 10 64bit
- JRE/JDK version: 1.8.0_181 64bit*( changed from 32 to 64bit )*
- Eclipse: Photon Release (4.8.0)
- Maven version: 3.5.4
- JACOB version: 1.14.3 (Both files 64[x64] and 32[x86])

**Here you can find the solutions that I already have try**

- [Add the jacob.jar as external library and add the folder where the dlls as native library.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvhm9.png)
- Use the command for the java library path 
  `–Djava.library.path=C:\Users\adazat\Downloads\ClienteImplantadoJava\jacob-1.14.3\`
- Added the dll files to `/Java/jdk/jre/bin` and `/Java/jdk/jre/lib/ext`
- Added the dependencies using maven commands

---

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\adazat\Downloads\ClienteImplantadoJava\jacob-1.14.3\jacob-1.14.3-x64.dll -DgroupId=jacob -DartifactId=jacob-dll  -Dversion=1.14.3 -Dpackaging=dll -DgeneratePom=true`

---

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\adazat\Downloads\ClienteImplantadoJava\jacob-1.14.3\jacob.jar -DgroupId=jacob -DartifactId=jacob-jar  -Dversion=1.14.3 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true`

- Added the dependencies to maven pom.xml

I have searched in different questions in stack-overflow and still does not work trying any approach, I would like to know if some has a kind of similar problem and what else iI could try, to solve it. I really appreciate your time :D

Comment: Are you using 64bit version of Jacob DLL with 64bit version of Java, ideally on a 64bit Windows? Perhaps you mixed up the versions.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Thanks for noticing that, I have edited the question and I added what types of dlls I am using and  the windows architecture. which is 64bit

Comment: What's your JDK? 32 or 64Bit? Please also add that since you can not access 64Bit Dlls from 32Bit Java....

Comment: Wow  @Lonzak That could be the problem, I will try to download the 64 bit version of JDK because at the moment I am working with the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, to your intitial question: Switch to a 64Bit JDK since a 64Bit dll can not be called from a 32bit jre/jdk.

Regarding your next error:

> Can't co-create object

Before using a COM object, it must be registered in the system (e.g. its CLSID or ProgID must exist in the Windows Registry). If its not registered, regasm.exe utility can be used to do that:

Use: `Regsvr32 PathToDll`

Or you may also try: `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\vX.X\RegAsm.exe /verbose /nologo /codebase PINPAD.dll`

(replace vX.X with the version installed on your system e.g. v3.0 or v4.0.30319. If you want to use the 32bit dll use `...\Framework\...` instead of `...\Framework64\...`)

Once it’s registered  `CoCreateInstance()` API method can be used to obtain a reference to an interface exposed by the object and call its methods. Furter details can be found [here](https://netheadaches.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/jacob-cant-co-create-object/).

Comment: Yes that's correct, I did that, I registered the Dlls. But for some reason I had to change the JDK and JRE to from 64bit to 32 bit as well and point to the 32bit Dll version.  Thank you :D for the Help.

Comment: Yes that would make sense if your pinpad.dll is 32 Bit. Then of course you need to use the jacob32 Bit version and probably also 32Bit jdk. Alltough 64Bit jdk should have worked, too...

Answer (score 0):

You have to verify if the `java.library.path` is correct.

I was writing `-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\adazat\Downloads\ClienteImplantadoJava\jacob-1.14.3\";` and `-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\adazat\Downloads\ClienteImplantadoJava\jacob-1.14.3\;` you have to make sure that you are not using

> - "" *to surround the path*
> - ; *at the end*
> - and that should be \ at the end of the path to indicate that is a folder that contains the dlls.

After I resolved it, now I am getting the following error when is program is executed.

`com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object`